# jQuery hover() event on div element within a button element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I can't seem to get jQuery to notice the div within the following markup

```
<button class="button submit positive right" id="omnisubmit" type="submit">
    <div class="label">Submit</div> 
    <div class="controller">&nbsp;</div>
</button>
```

And here is the jQuery I'm currently using:

```
$("button#omnisubmit div.controller").hover(function () {
            console.log("Hover...");
        });
```

However, jQuery doesn't seem to pick up when the mouse is hovering over that div, `$("button#omnisubmit div.controller").hover(...` works correctly, of course.

I have a feeling it's because putting divs inside buttons may not be standard HTML?

Comment: I can't really understand why you'd want to do this anway

Comment: It's so the consequence of pressing the button can be changed by the user: http://img.skitch.com/20100324-x8gm3725b34tk23ghiy7ty8tgb.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you really should do is have two button elements that are styled to look like one.

Something like the [jQuery UI Button element split button example.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton)

Comment: urgh! OK, I need to go home and have a good sleep, should have totally thought of that. Thanks man. It's always nice when people just give a brilliant answer rather than an obnoxious comment :)